# CSS selector applying style to only parent link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having some problems getting my CSS selector to pick the parent link only.

```
<style>
.sidebar .nav li a {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #563D7C;
    color: #563D7C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<div class="sidebar">
<ul class="nav sidenav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu1</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu2</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately.. the style applying to ALL links in the nav, my alternative is to put a class on all of the links I want styled, but rather not have to do that.

http://jsfiddle.net/bFxm4/

Comment: Why are you against making a class? If you ever need to restructure this site, using a class will make it both more readable and easier to change

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bFxm4/6/

Comment: Selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this work [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bFxm4/3/) :

```
.sidebar .nav.sidenav > li > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #563D7C;
    color: #563D7C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The ">" means : picks the ones which are **directly** child

Comment: This worked exactly what I was looking for.. did something similar but didnt have the .sidenav which solved it..

Answer (score 8):

> A **child selector** matches when an element is the child of some element.
>   A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by `>`.

[CSS 2.0 Specifications - Selectors, 5.6 Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

```
.sidebar .nav > li > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #563D7C;
    color: #563D7C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGUBf/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that putting a class on all of the parent links is fine. Especially is you are using some loop on the back end to generate the html, then adding a class to each one is simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the style to apply to `.sidebar .nav li a` only, and not the links in the nested lists, you can change your selector to read like this: `.sidebar .nav > li > a`.  This targets `<a>` tags that are direct descendants of `<li>` tags only, and only those that are in the top level list.  It won't go any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.sidebar > .nav > li > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #563D7C;
    color: #563D7C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

hope this helps